# problem with array of object javascript ad property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, properties

I have this function that accepts an array of objects as input and transforms it into an array of strings, but when I do the console log the property are wrong, I can't understand why.
as you can see the two console logs are of the same object, in the first the `x.credititoTotale` property has a value in the second console.log where I go to access it directly with `x.credititoTotale` has another value

```
const stringArray = [];
export const convertToStringForDb = (objectArray) => {
  objectArray.forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x.credititoTotale + " " + x.id);
    stringArray.push(
      `${x.id}/${x.cognome}/${x.nome}/${x.totaleCG}/${x.time}/${x.credititoTotale}`
    );
  });

  return stringArray;
};
```

look the screen ---> [screen of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcbYm.png)

when I print x the value of 'credititoTotale' is '-20'
when I print x.credititoTotale the value is '-10'

it should always be the same because it is the same object printed in the same for loop

Comment: 1- you should use map instead of forEach here ; 2- what is the type of the object in objectArray ? theres probably something inside the object definition that leads to this behavior.

Comment: Your code looks perfect, I did not see any issue in that. Here is the working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/oev3L7br/

Comment: yes also I had tested it separately but I don't understand why if I use it in the context where I should use it it gives me this error is something that I can not explain. As you can see from the console.log image I posted from two different values